# Why isn't netrw (:Explore) loaded, when starting vim using `vim -u NONE`?

Tags: netrw

I wonder why `netrw` (`:Explore`) is not loaded after starting `vim` using `vim -u NONE`.

Inspecting my `runtimepath` yields:
`/Users/shuz/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim82,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/Users/shuz/.vim/after`

, so common Vim directories are indeed present in the `runtimepath`.

If not the `runtimepath`, what mechanism causes `netrw` to be loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

netrw is a plugin, just one that is distributed with vim itself.  For me, `:Explore` and friends are defined in `/usr/local/share/vim/vim82/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim`.

From the `load-plugins` section of `:h initialization`, step 4:

> 4. Load the plugin scripts.
>
> This does the same as the command:
>
> :runtime! plugin/**/*.vim
>
> The result is that all
> directories in the 'runtimepath' option will be   searched for the
> "plugin" sub-directory and all files ending in ".vim"     will be sourced
> (in alphabetical order per directory), also in    subdirectories.
> However, directories in 'runtimepath' ending in "after" are skipped
> here and only loaded after packages, see below.     Loading plugins
> won't be done when:
>
> - The 'loadplugins' option was reset in a vimrc file.
> - The |--noplugin| command line argument is used.
> - The |--clean| command line argument is used.
> - The "-u NONE" command line argument is used |-u|.
> - When Vim was compiled without the |+eval| feature.

Therefore, netrw is not loaded with `-u NONE`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why `:Explore` isn't loaded after executing `:runtime! plugin/**/*.vim` after starting Vim as `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: That's because if you look at the first few uncommented lines of `netrwPlugin.vim`, it doesn't load the plugin if `compatible` is set (the default).  It will load if you do `vim -u NONE`, then `:set nocompatible | runtime! plugin/**/*.vim`.  Of course, whether or not that's the right thing to do depends on what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You also need `nocompatible` to be set. That's usually the default, but not for `-u NONE` or `-u empty-vimrc`.

```sh
echo '' > empty-vimrc

# These do work
vim -u empty-vimrc -N .                       # sets nocompatible via -N
vim -u empty-vimrc --cmd 'set nocompatible' . # sets nocompatible before vimrc is loaded

# These don't work
vim -u empty-vimrc -c 'set nocompatible' .    # sets nocompatible after vimrc is loaded, too late
vim -u NONE --cmd 'set nocompatible' .        # -u NONE never works, as pointed out in previous answer
```

Comment: In many shells you could also write `vim -u <(echo)` or use `-u NORC`